# Attaching an entity of type.. failed because

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am experiencing strange behavior with my Edit action on one of my controllers.

Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,FirstName,LastName,Email,deleted,AId")] Information personInformation)
{

    // to stop multiple calls to database
    var lstOfPeople = db.Information.Where(x => x.deleted == false).ToList();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        if (lstOfPeople.Any(x => x.Email.Equals(personInformation.Email, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && x.ID != personInformation.ID))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "This email already exists!");
            return View(personInformation);
        }

        db.Entry(personInformation).State = EntityState.Modified; // error here
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(personInformation);
}
```

Now I have pretty much the exact same code in a different controller edit action and it works fine.  Here that is:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,RNumber,DateCreated,PersonWhoCreated,deleted")] OtherTable oTable)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (db.OtherTable.Any(x => x.RNumber.Equals(oTable.RNumber, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && x.ID != oTable.ID))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("RNumber", "This number already exists!");
            return View(oTable);
        }

        db.Entry(oTable).State = EntityState.Modified; // no error here.. goes through fine.
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(oTable);
}
```

Error I am receiving:

> Attaching an entity of type 'ProjectName.Models.Information' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.  This can happen when using 'Attach'.. etc.

Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: What is the primary key on `Information`? Also is proxy generation enabled on your entity set?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange `ID` is the primary key on Information.. how do I check for proxy generation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `db.Entry(personInformation).State` attachs the `personInformation` object to the EF context, the error raises because the EF data context has previously loaded a diferent `Information` instance with the same id (perhaps in the previous `Where()` you are doing).

There are at least two basic options:

- first one is to **use the AsNoTracking() extension for your queries**, (as in `db.Information.AsNoTracking()`) this extension tells EF data context to not keep the entities retrieved from database in memory so you can attach your `personInformation` entity directly to the context and set the modified state.
- second option is **retrieve the entity from the ef data context and modify that entity** (not the personInformation instance). You can retrieve the entity with `db.Information.FindAsync` and the EF context will retrieve from memory if it is previously attached.

```
    var attachedEntity = db.Information.FindAsync(personInformation.ID);
    attachedEntity.ExampleValue = personInformation.ExampleValue;
    attachedEntity.ExampleValue2 = personInformation.ExampleValue2;
    ...
    and so on
```

Comment: Worked also for removing from database (AsNoTracking()), thanks!